# Is there a way to do vlookup using python?

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have two dataframes df1 and df2 and I need to do vlookup on name and give out names which are matching.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'val1': [5, 6, 7, 8],
    'val2': [1, 2, 3, 4],
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['B', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
    'abc': [15, 16, 17, 18],
    'def': [11, 21, 31, 41],
})

Expected Output:
name    val1    val2    matched_name
A          5       1    NaN
B          6       2    B
C          7       3    NaN
D          8       4    D
```

I thought this could be done by:

```
df1['matched_name'] = df1['name'].map(df2['name'])
```

But I'm getting all NaN's in matched column. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What should be done about `abc` and `def` in the other DF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the numpy *where* which will see if the name exists in the other dataframes name column and since the names are exact match, you can use the value in first dataframe:

```
df1['matched_name']=np.where(df1.name.isin(df2.name),df1.name,np.nan)
```

This gives the output as:

```
  name  val1  val2 matched_name
0    A     5     1          NaN
1    B     6     2            B
2    C     7     3          NaN
3    D     8     4            D
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not really a vlookup, but you can use [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df1['matched_name'] = df1['name'].where(df1['name'].isin(df2['name']))
```

A more convoluted way, using a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), which allows you to also add other columns if needed:

```
out = df1.merge(df2[['name']].rename(columns={'name': 'matched_name'}),
                left_on='name', right_on='matched_name', how='left')
```

Output:

```
  name  val1  val2 matched_name
0    A     5     1          NaN
1    B     6     2            B
2    C     7     3          NaN
3    D     8     4            D
```